# Setting up a separate network in an already existing one

Tags: networking, router

I want to accomplish the following:

[image: network_setup]

The 192.168.0.x network already exists, I want to set up the 192.168.2.x network inside it. Router1 is a generic cheap gigabit router, not capable of static routes. I would also like to make a web server on the 192.168.2.x network accessible from the 192.168.0.x network. How should I set up the Cisco router to accomplish this?

Comment: If your main router is "not capable of static routes" then you will need to either replace the router with one that is or statically define the route in each node on 192.168.0.0/24 to know how to reach the 192.168.2.0/24 network via the Cisco router's gateway address. The setup in the Cisco would be very simple since it isn't the "brains" in this connection at all.

Comment: More info is needed. What is the make and model of router1, and why don't you simy replace it with the Cisco? Why do you need 2 subnets and does the web server need to be world accessible?  You said that 192.168.2.x needs to sit inside 192.168.0.x - this is impossible because they are non-overlapping ranges - what are you trying to achieve with this constraint?

Answer (score -1):

Assign some address from 192.168.0.x on one of its interfaces, say 192.168.0.11, and set 192.168.2.1 on the other. Enable DHCP on the second interface if you like.

As the cheap gigabit router is not capable of static routes in this scenario, which is weird of course, you have to define a route to 192.168.2.x via 1st interface of Cisco router (e.g. that 192.168.0.11) on each node in first network who wants to access 2nd network. Therefore Cisco router simply routes things and nothing more it can do to force systems on first network see the second.

Comment: I don't know a lot about Cisco gear, can you help how should I do what you said?

Comment: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/interface/configuration/guide/finter_c/icflanin.html